# Add surrounding XML tag on XML response?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there an easy way to wrap the XML response of a controller action into something like `<response>@model.to_xml</response>` without creating an extra `response` model?

The `respond_with` looks something like:

```
respond_with(@model, :status => :accepted, :location => nil) do |format|
  format.xml { render :xml => @model.to_xml(:dasherize => false) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
respond_with(@model, :status => :accepted, :location => nil) do |format|
  format.xml { 
    render :xml => {:response => @model}.to_xml(:dasherize => false) 
  }
end
```